# Self-dual Lie Algebra representation

Tags: lie-algebras

If $V$ is a Lie algebra $L$ module, then I want to know whether if $V$ and $V^*$ are isomorphic as $L$ modules then there is a basis for $V$ in which the matrices representing the action of $L$ are all skew-symmetric. If there is a basis $(e_i)$ for which the isomorphism takes $e_i$ to $e_i^*$ then I can do the problem. But is there such a basis?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3953914/96384

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $L$ is a real semi-simple algebra. Let $K$ its killing form, it is not degenerated, there exists an isomorphism $L\rightarrow L^*$ defined by $L(x)=K(x,.)$, but if $L$ is for example $sl(2,\mathbb{R})$, the matrices of the adjoint representation are not all skew-symmetric for a given basis since you have an element $h$ such that $ad_h$ has $2$ as an eigenvalue.

Comment: But $L$ and $L^*$ are isomorphic as Lie algebras, why should they be isomorphic as $L$ modules?

Comment: @justanothermathstudent The adjoint representation of any semisimple real Lie algebra is self-dual, see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/168182/is-the-adjoint-representation-of-so4-self-dual).

Answer (score 0):

While Tsemo Aristide's answer shows via striking examples that the answer is "no", I would like to quickly explain what I think is the mistake in the question. Full disclosure: This is partly due to me making the same mistake at first when thinking about the related question [Under what conditions can we find a basis of a Lie algebra such that the adjoint representation acts by skew-symmetric matrices?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3953914/96384) today.

An isomorphism of $\mathfrak g$-modules $V \simeq V^*$ indeed is equivalent to the existence of a non-degenerate $\mathfrak g$-invariant bilinear form $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle$ on $V$ (NB, $\mathfrak g$-invariant for Lie algebra representations i.e. $\mathfrak g$-modules means $\langle x v ,w\rangle = -\langle v, x w\rangle$). (Compare also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3781591/96384 .)

Further, in the case of a *simple* $\mathfrak g$-module, and $\mathfrak g$ being absolutely simple, this form is even unique up to a scalar (as follows from Schur's Lemma.)

Now in general this form does not need to be symmetric, it can be alternating. E.g. for the fundamental representation of $\mathfrak {sl}_2(\mathbb C)$ on $V:=\mathbb C^2$, check that up to a scalar, that non-degenerate bilinear form is the alternating $\langle \pmatrix{x\\y}, \pmatrix{w\\z} \rangle := \det(\pmatrix{x &w \\y &z})$. However e.g. for the adjoint representation, one can show that it is always symmetric. Indeed, up to a scalar it is the Killing form.

So why is the assertion still not (generally) true in that case, as Tsemo Aristide's answer and [this here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3953914/96384) show? Because to get to skew-symmetric matrices from a symmetric bilinear form with the method shown by Malkoun in their answer there, you need an orthonormal basis, and for that you need the form to be *much more than non-degenerate*, you need it to have an *orthonormal basis* i.e. being equivalent up to scaling to the form given by the symmetric matrix $S= Id$ (where in general, you represent a symmetric BLF $b(\cdot, \cdot)$ by any symmetric matrix $S$ via $b(x,y) := x^{tr}Sy$). Now over an algebraically closed field like $\mathbb C$, every symmetric BLF is equivalent to that standard one. But e.g. over $\mathbb R$, where due to [Sylvester's Law of Inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia) symmetric BLFs are classified by their index, this is equivalent to the form being *anisotropic* i.e. (positive or negative) *definite*. Which over the real numbers it is only in the case of semisimple Lie algebras which come from *compact* Lie groups. Indeed, since the Killing form is indefinite as soon as our Lie algebra contains nonzero nilpotent elements, this shows that over any subfield of $\mathbb R$ there is no hope to represent all $ad(x)$ for $x$ in a given semisimple Lie algbera with skew-symmetric matrices, unless the Lie algebra contains only semisimple elements i.e. is anisotropic ("compact").