# Defining a positive definite killing form

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, inner-products, semisimple-lie-algebras

Physicist here and I am struggling to understand my lecturers construction of the roots and weights system.

As I understand it the killing form for a semi-simple lie algebra is non degenerate on $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{h}$ where $\mathfrak{h}$ is the Cartan subalgebra. This induces an inner product and an isomorphism between $\mathfrak{h}$ and $\mathfrak{h}*$. Roots are then elements of the dual cartan subalgebra $\mathfrak{h}*$.

I understand that if the Lie Group is compact then we can choose a basis in the lie algebra such that the killing form takes the form $\kappa_{ij}= -\kappa \delta_{ij}$ for $\kappa >0$.

In my lecture notes my lecturer has equipped the cartan subalgebra and its dual with the euclidean inner product, ie the dot product. I do not understand why this is ok.

Comment: It might be helpful to see an example for a small ($\dim \mathfrak{h}$ 1 or 2) case. As an aside, pretty much any inner product where the Weyl group acts by unitary (or orthogonal) transformations on $\mathfrak{h}^*$ will be “good”, as in the formulas will at most be affected by a positive real scalar.

Comment: As long as an (here: ad-)invariant bilinear form on any Lie algebra representation $V$ (here, $\mathfrak g$ or $\mathfrak h$ with natural (adjoint) action) is non-degenerate, it provides us with an isomorphism of that representation $V$ with its dual $V^*$. No need for definiteness (which would make sense only over $\mathbb R$ anyway, whereas the roots live in the dual of the *complexified* Cartan subalgebra).

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3980472/euclidean-property-of-the-killing-form).